# Cannot insert data in SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am able to use `SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)` method to insert rows to the database. But for some reason, I cannot do it using raw SQL statement inside `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`. The `CREATE` command does work, but the `INSERT` commands does not. No SQLException was thrown.

Here is the code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "CREATE TABLE " + MyDatabaseContract.Release.TABLE_NAME;
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\n(\n\t";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += MyDatabaseContract.Release._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n\t";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += MyDatabaseContract.Release.COLUMN_NAME_VERSION + " TEXT NOT NULL,\n\t";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += MyDatabaseContract.Release.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,\n\t";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += MyDatabaseContract.Release.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " INTEGER,\n\t";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += MyDatabaseContract.Release.COLUMN_NAME_CHANGELOG + " TEXT";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\n);";

    // Insert some test data
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\n\nINSERT INTO " + MyDatabaseContract.Release.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(1, '8.0a', 3, 1234567890, 'Initial release');";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\nINSERT INTO " + MyDatabaseContract.Release.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(2, '9.0c', 2, 1434567890, 'Fix bugs');";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\nINSERT INTO " + MyDatabaseContract.Release.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(3, '9.1', 5, 1634567890, 'Add new features');";
    SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES += "\nINSERT INTO " + MyDatabaseContract.Release.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(4, '9.22', 6, 1834567890, 'Final version');";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}
```

I wrote the `SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES` out into a file:

```
CREATE TABLE Releases
(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Version TEXT NOT NULL,
    Type INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Date INTEGER,
    Changelog TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Releases VALUES(1, '8.0a', 3, 1234567890, 'Initial release');
INSERT INTO Releases VALUES(2, '9.0c', 2, 1434567890, 'Fix bugs');
INSERT INTO Releases VALUES(3, '9.1', 5, 1634567890, 'Add new features');
INSERT INTO Releases VALUES(4, '9.22', 6, 1834567890, 'Final version');
```

I find nothing unusual. What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: No luck. I even removed the `AUTOINCREMENT` and still, no row was inserted. Note that I was able to use `SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)` to insert data, which means the table had been successfully created.

Comment: I've spent a day debugging to no avail (already tried removing the primary key values). And according to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (section 6.2 example), you **can** insert primary key, just like you do in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execSQL()` executes just one SQL statement. If you have more SQL after a `;`, it will be ignored.

Split your SQL at `;` to separate statements and execute each one individually with `execSQL()`.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29):

> sql   the SQL statement to be executed. Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.

Under the hood it boils down to how [`sqlite3_prepare*()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) works:

> These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.

Tools such as sqlite3 keep preparing and executing new statements until the input tail is exhausted or an error occurs.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. This means that the **;** is completely useless... As always, you're our guide into SQLite! +1